How to secure Firebase API keys that comes with google-services.json or GoogleService-Info.plist
I use Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) in my mobile app. Firebase requires configuration files like google-services.json, GoogleService-Info.plist, firebase_app_id_file.json, and firebase_options.dart. While these can be excluded from version control using .gitignore, I'm concerned about reverse engineering exposing these API keys.
After extensive research, I found conflicting information:

This answer suggests using Firebase App Check for protection.

Another response indicates these config files aren't strictly private, implying API keys can be used freely.

This answer explains that Firebase API keys only identify the project and don't pose a security risk alone. They recommend Firebase App Check with user authentication for enhanced security.

This post states it's acceptable to share API keys on GitHub as they only identify the project.

A Google Groups discussion mentions that while google-services.json doesn't contain highly sensitive information, improper security rules could make these details exploitable.

This Medium article recommends:

Restricting API keys through Google Console
Adding SHA-1 certificate fingerprints alongside package names
Limiting API access permissions



Current Security Measures Implemented:

Added package name restrictions
Included SHA-1 fingerprint restrictions
Limited API access
Set up proper Firebase security rules

Question:
Despite implementing these security measures, I'm still concerned about potential API key abuse. I think these measures are not enough. Are there additional steps I should take to better protect google-services.json, GoogleService-Info.plist, firebase_app_id_file.json, and firebase_options.dart files? What are the best practices for handling Firebase configuration security in production mobile apps?

The IDs in these files are not sensitive. They don't provide access to any Google APIs and they need to be embedded in your app. As one of the answers you linked to said, including them in an open source repo is not the best idea because others may not realise that they need to set up their own project.

You've linked to all of the information that you need to make a decision about your project.  It's ultimately a matter of personal or organizational preference what you do with your configuration data (which as you already know, does not itself cause security problems).
